# Azure website domain names when migrating to new subscription

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, cname

I have a domain on Azure subscription A (www and no www).  Our client added the proper awverify cnames and everything has worked great for the last few months.  Now, I need to move them to a separate Azure subscription.  I migrated the site to the new subscription (the current site is still live on the original subscription).  I'm trying to determine the best way to switch the domains.  The IP of the azure website is actually the same (for both subscriptions), but I am timid about switching the awverify cnames in order to add the domain to the new site.  I don't want any downtime.

What's the best strategy?

Comment: re: the dns change.
I recieved a good answer to my similar question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747972/azure-migrating-website-hostnames

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: ask support to move the web site (and any other associated assets - storage acct, database) from the current account to the new account. I'm not sure they can, but **if** they can, that may be simplest and least risky since the site itself would not change or need to experience any downtime.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we had to remove the domain names from the original site and add them to the new site.  This wasn't ideal, but it worked.  It would be nice to be alerted by Azure that  the domains wouldn't work on the new subscription site until removed from the old.  Having support migrate the site would work, but didn't give me warm fuzzies that the Orchard CMS would remain intact through the process.